# Restricting website usage for Google Maps API doesn't prevent it from being used in the browser?

Tags: web-browser, google, api

Say I've restricted my Google Maps API key to the website `example.com/*`. This would mean that no other website domains could use my API key to make requests to `maps.googleapis.com`.

However, using the API key through the browser address bar to make requests to `maps.googleapis.com` still works fine. Calls made through Postman also work.

What's the explanation for this and is there an elegant way to prevent this?

Btw, I'm using the Maps Static & Javascript API. From my understanding both are client-side Maps API and called from the browser?

Comment: This is looking more like a Google API question than a security question. If you set the restriction by referer, did you set a referer in Postman?

Comment: I didn't set a referer in Postman but my concern is that the api call isn't declined by `maps.googleapis.com`. So even without a referer header, it looks like the call succeeds.



Example API call:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=45%2C10&zoom=7&size=400x400&key={API Key}`

Comment: Sure, I get your concern, I'm just not sure it's a security question that fits here. It sounds more like a Google support scenario: "why isn't the referrer restriction working?" Or a debugging scenario.

Comment: That's a valid point. It's just quicker to get feedback on forums like these compared to Google Support.

I'll probably submit a support ticket to Google and close this question then.

Comment: Note that `This would mean that no other website domains could use my API key to make requests to maps.googleapis.com.` isn't really true.  Google has no idea who is calling their API, and no way to tell.  Google _may_ have stopped doing filtering because it could be providing a false sense of security, in favor of recommending better security around API keys

Comment: Particularly for static maps there does not seem to be any check at all any more. This may be due to fundamental browser security updates as in fact the site is not the API client, the browser is, and it may be trivial to spoof the referrer by various means.  Signing does not help you either if it is the same map they want. So deep linking II "the borrowing" ensues.